# Lifecycle of Files copied to a docker container

Tags: docker, containers, docker-build

I'm a Docker newbie and I fired the following command which successfully copied the file to a running container.

`sudo docker cp app.py 943395e93d1d:/app/app.py`

Note : The container was already contains a app.py and so my guess was that because app.py is running inside the container it will not allow the copy .

I did another thing now

`sudo docker cp sample.txt 943395e93d1d:/app/sample.txt`

Now this also went successfully .

My question : Will the sample.txt file continue to exist within the container even after I stop the container ? So that if I start it again the updated files are there .

Because that means I don't build the docker file again and again but just copy the files if there are changes in some assets of my application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you copy in with `docker cp` will be lost as soon as the container exits.  I'd use this command sparingly.  It's certainly not a way to update your code; re-run `docker build` when your application changes.

(In typical use, with an interpreted language where just copying in source code is enough, re-running `docker build` should be very quick.  It will generally know to skip over time-consuming dependency installation and just `COPY` in the new source code.  Even if you only have a single container using Docker Compose to drive things will give you a single place to list out the options you need to run it.)